# Where is the Science lab in Sims 3? Oh My Ghost Opportunity

Tags: the-sims-3

My dog died in Sims 3, and I was an idiot and forgot to click 'show me location'. I keep looking all over the map and I see any science lab symbol.

Is there a way to find out where the lab is after accepting an opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

I found the lab. I had to go to the Wikia page of the town my sims where in to see what it was called: http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Riverview#Community_lots

In my case it was called 'Soil and Water Research Facility'(which sounds like it has the furthest thing to do with resurrecting an animal), and didn't have a science lab symbol on it strangely enough.

If anyone finds themselves in a similar situation I just recommend they look up the Wikia of the town their sims live in and see if the list of names of buildings in their towns.